# Exporting WebSQL Data

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite, local-storage

One of the major problems with WebSQL is its vulnerability to losing data. Every time the browser history is deleted so is the data stored in your WebSQL tables. Is there any way to export/download the WebSQL data or write it to a file, using only Javascript to prevent data loss? I know you can't access the file system from JavaScript so is this even possible to do? Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to download your *own* data stored in a WebSQL database by another application? Or are you trying to build an app that stores data on a WebSQL database, and you want to provide users with their own data?

Comment: The application stores users data for them in the webSQL, for example it will store messages from other users. This data needs to be available until the user decides to remove it. Therefore I need a way to download this data when the user deletes their browser history and allow the user to restore this data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get all the data into a JavaScript variable and then `document.location` to it.

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:onDownload();">Download</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
function onDownload() {
    document.location = 'data:Application/octet-stream,' +
                         encodeURIComponent(dataToDownload);
}
```

(Taken from this blog post: [How to Download Data as a File from JavaScript](http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2012/01/how-to-download-data-as-a-file-from-javascript.html))

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Any ideas how I could do this on a mobile device?

Comment: Hmm. Did you try it? On Android, it may save the data to downloads. Not sure what it would do in iOS. In PhoneGap, you can write to the local file system in both.