# Store/Backup Database into a file, differences of IndexeDB, WebSQL and SQLlite?

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite, indexeddb, web-sql

My question is about *IndexedDB* vs. *WebSQL* vs. *SQLite*. There is no need to explain that they are different, what I would like to know is:

Do those three "*Database Solutions*" allow for storing all its Data
to a file?
(and of course to do the reverse, initialize all its data given a backup file?)
.

#### Background

Since I already have done some research, which partly answers this question, allow me to provide this background info to the question:

#### SQLite

(**yes** it does allow storage and retrievel of the Database to and from a file)
I have already done some work with SQLite. For this I know that there it actually right away starts the database via a reference to the file. Backup is simple copying the file. Restoring is rewriting the file.

#### IndexedDB and WebSQL

**???** Are to my understanding Database Solutions which "life their life in the Browser's Javascript land" and there we do not deal much with files. Here is part of where the question lies. If I wanted to export the data from either of the two solution to a flat file or lets say a one string variable representation, would that be possible?

This are some SO question I think that relate to it:

- [SO Question: Exporting WebSQL Data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11696365/1711186)
- [SO Question: Import and Export Indexeddb data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17783719/1711186)

which indicate that there is no easy `toString()` (Store Database) method and `FromSting()` in *IndexedDB* nor in *WebSQL*.
It indeed true (and affirmed in an answer here) and there is not easy backup and retrieval for those Database, this would be very sad, and I think a gap. Databases without backup function, really?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At Present, there is no way to back up and restore Browser databases. The only way you can achieve this is by continuously syncing your back-end database with the browser database and thus keep track of changes in data generated on browser.

Comment: Let us hope "At Present,....", that such a smart featuer will eventually be enabled. The trueth is that the Browser itself must store the data somewhere and the chances are good that is not a very fragmented difuese thing, but a file or continous memory part. If this was to become standardized then it would be possible to use this data as a convenient way of backup. Still I am yet not very happy with the shortcomings of IndexedDB. One cannot even store sn object like this in an IndexedDB objectstore: `var obj={prop1:12, prop2:function(){alert("hello world");}};

Answer (score 0):

Old guy will do in old way, whether appropriate or not. How on earth, browser database need a backup. Data in the client is just cache copy of a slice of server data. There is no need back. If you think IndexedDB (or web sql database) data is durable, you will be glad to know, IndexedDB data belong to a [temporary class](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-quota-api-20120703/#temporary) of browser data, meaning that UA can delete data at their discretion without prompting to user or app.

If your app treat browser data more than cache copy, you are doing wrong.

Comment: thank you for your answer attempt. There are some insights, but I honestly. Asking if I can backup or serialize all the Database data (in case of IndexedDB and WebSQL) makes most sense not despite, but because it is possible that data can get lost out of sudden. I would very much like to accept your answer if the style was less a complaining and more geared to telling if there is a way to store data in the volantile storage (and that is the reason after all) that is IndexedDB etc. Reading again, I see no helpful answer how to backup, just a complain "you should not backup". sorry

Comment: Kyaw, I disagree with you. IndexedDB can be used for much more than a cache. As an example, [here is a game I wrote](http://play.basketball-gm.com/). All data is stored in IndexedDB. There is no server-side component other than serving static JS/HTML/CSS. Despite that, the game works. So far today, people have played it for over 1000 hours. It's fast, simple, and easy to get running. No user accounts, no downloads, etc. This is only possible because of IndexedDB. I would love it if my users could easily backup or export saved games, but it's currently impossible (or very difficult).

Comment: Nice game! I see. In browser database, backup is same as synchronizing back to the server.